# Cross-platform JAD (Java Decompiler) (Or Alternative?)

Tags: java, jar, cross-platform, decompiler

I'm in a situation where I will be decompiling quite a bit of existing JARs.  I've found JAD to be quite useful and even took a look into [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/).

The problem I'm facing now is that I may very well have to switch environments.  I'll probably be on something *nix but most likely CentOS or Ubuntu.  Are there any good cross-platform Java Decompilers?  JAD appears to be Windows only.  I can't do too much research on the topic because the original site doesn't exist either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with JAD?
[Here's a link to JAD downloads mirror site](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) with downloads for many different systems platforms.

Comment: Looks good, which of those would I use for something such as CentOS?

Comment: Try the _for Linux_ version provided for your platform (Intel/Sun). Unzip the archive and set the executable flag to `jad` file using `chmod +x jad`.

Comment: alright, many thanks!  I deem this question... ***answered!***

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of alternative-to-jad decompilers as of Feb 2015:

- Procyon, open-source
- CFR, free, no source-code available
- JD, free for non-commercial use only
- Fernflower, open-source

You may test above mention decompilers online, no installation required and make your own educated choice. Java decompilers in the cloud:  http://www.javadecompilers.com/